# Aligning div to center of page

Tags: html, css

```
<div style="text-align:center;">
        <select id="sponsorList"></select>&nbsp;<img alt="Loading..." src="../../Img/ajax-loader.gif" id="loader" />
        <span style="display:none;" id="selectedSponsorId"></span>
        <div id="sponsorRowDetails" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Effective Date: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="startDate" /><br /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>End Date: </td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="endDate" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So the `select` box is in the center, but I can't get everything within the `sponsorRowDetails` center aligned as well.

I'm terrible with simple CSS things like this. What am I doing wrong? I also tried `text-align:center;` with the other div, as well as just keeping the table directly in the first div.

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you're wanting to achieve. Are you wanting your table's elements' text to be center-aligned?

Comment: I just want the whole div that the table is inside of to be center aligned on the page, the entire table itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this instead for the table inside your sponsorRowDetails `div`

`<table align="center" style="margin: 0 auto;">`

Answer (score 0):

Give the `<table>` a width and then apply `margin:0 auto;`, that will center the table in the container.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that a div is by default 100% the width of it's parent.  so setting `margin: 0 auto;` on a width of 100% will not do anything.  If you want to center it you need to give the div a width and then you can apply the `margin: auto;` otherwise set `text-align: center;` on the `sponsorRowDetails`