# How to set the div in center of the page

Tags: css

http://jsfiddle.net/VjMy8/

Please help me to set the #container to keep in the center of the page so that all other contents under the #container will be on center.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Aligning div to center of page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014004/aligning-div-to-center-of-page)

Comment: Dude, this has been answered 100 times already. Please look harder.

Comment: @ismailvittal -- u need to accept an answer after it solves your problem.. accept the answer which most suits/fixes your problem.. and please search before you post a question here.. common issues are already solved..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in css:

```
#container {
    width: xxx em/px/%/...;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    /* or margin: 0 auto; */
}
```

With this method you won't even need a container, you can do something like this the code below.
This code doesn't need a float, so it doesn't interrupt the flow of a page

```
#div_left {
    width: 25%;
    margin-left: 12%;
}
#div_right {
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 38%;
}
```

This method works in every browser in is much easyer then this (older & longer) method:

```
body {
    text-algin: center;
}
#container {
    width: xxx;
    text-align: center;
}
#div_left {
    width: 30%; /* 30% of the container-width */
}
#div_right {
    width: 70%;
}
```

Comment: Better would be `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: @JannisM true, but was forgotten that it was 'top left bottom right'

Comment: @groundzero he had just added `float:left` which was the problem -- without which it'll be centered.. your code is redundant!!

Comment: I think you've made a mistake, `#container` should have `text-align: right`.

Comment: @MMM the bottom one is the 'old' code. This was using a align center in the body to center the container and a align left (normal left-to-right text-align). The 1st code is the shorter (& better) code.

Answer (score 1):

just remove the float left -- here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mvivekc/VjMy8/3/

Comment: You did do one other thing—you removed what looks like an attempted comment from the CSS (`//` before `margin:0 auto;`).

Comment: @NathanArthur removed `float:left` which was preventing the container from coming to the center -- and the comment was just wrong!!.. syntax error and you need `margin:0 auto` inorder to get it to the center!!.. he wanted it in the center,i got it to the center - minor changes to his code..

Comment: Yes, indeed. It's just always nice when all changes are noted so that the questioner, even if inexperienced, is able to implement the solution.

Comment: @nathanarthur yeah,if he's that interested in knowing where he went wrong - he would have had the patience to ask -- usually,they come - get the answer and leave - no understanding nor efficiency required.. this 1st answer solved ismail's problem so.. he came,he saw : he accepted and he left.. ;) ..